# Java Program: Not printing as it should using methods

Tags: java, methods

As you can see near the end of the code, i use "list.printList" that calls the printLink method. It should output "book name: ... book author:.. etc. " instead, it shows raw text file data. What am i doing wrong? Also, any recommendations are welcome. thanks

EDIT:  this is the the content of the text file:

```
antrea ggfg 65 64
antrea ggfg 65 64
antrea ggfg 65 64
antrea ggfg 65 64
```

This is the output:

```
antrea ggfg 65 64
antrea ggfg 65 64
antrea ggfg 65 64
antrea ggfg 65 64
```

Also i believe there is something wrong with the tokenizer. from your experience, what is SHOULD do as written below?

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.* ;

class Link
{
    public String isbn ;
    public String bookName ;
    public String bookAuthor ; 
    public String publicYear;
    public Link nextLink;

    public Link ()
    {

    }
    //Link constructor
    public Link(String bookNameIn, String bookAuthorIn, String isbnIn, String publicYearIn) 
    {
        setIsbn (isbnIn) ;
        setBookName (bookNameIn) ;
        setBookAuthor (bookAuthorIn) ;
        setPublicYear (publicYearIn) ;
        //isbn = isbnIn ;
        //bookAuthor = bookAuthorIn ;
        //publicYear = publicYearIn ;
    }

  // Set Methods
    public void setIsbn(String isbnIn)
    {
        isbn = isbnIn ;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookNameIn)
    {
        bookName = bookNameIn ;
    }

    public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthorIn)
    {
        bookAuthor = bookAuthorIn ;
    }

    public void setPublicYear(String publicYearIn)
    {
        publicYear = publicYearIn ;
    }

  // Get Methods
    public String getIsbn()
    {
        return isbn ;
    }

    public String getBookName()
    {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getBookAuthor()
    {
        return bookAuthor ;
    }

    public String getPublicYear()
    {
        return publicYear ;
    }   

    //Print Link data
    public void printLink()
    {
            System.out.print("Book Name: " + getBookName() + "\n" + "Book's Author: " + getBookAuthor() + "\n" + "Year Published: " + getPublicYear() + "\n" + "ISBN: " + getIsbn() +"\n");
            System.out.println("") ;
    }
}

class LinkList 
{

    private Link first;

    //LinkList constructor
    public LinkList()
    {
            first = null;
    }

    //Returns true if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
            return first == null;
    }

    //Inserts a new Link at the first of the list
    public void insert(String bookNameIn, String bookAuthorIn, String isbnIn, String publicYearIn) 
    {
            Link link = new Link(bookNameIn, bookAuthorIn, isbnIn, publicYearIn) ;
            link.nextLink = first;
            first = link;
    }

    //Deletes the link at the first of the list
    public Link delete() 
    {
            Link temp = first;
            first = first.nextLink;
            return temp;
    }

    //Prints list data
    public void printList()
    {
            Link currentLink = new Link() ;
            currentLink = first;
            while(currentLink != null) {
                    currentLink.printLink();
                    currentLink = currentLink.nextLink;
            }
            System.out.println("");
    }
}  

public class TheList 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
            //Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in); 
            LinkList list = new LinkList();
            File outputFile ;
            //int numberOfBooks = 0 ;

         // Create the new text file. If exists, it will continue to the next commands
            do
            {
                outputFile = new File("db.txt") ;

                    if(!outputFile.exists())
                    {
                        outputFile.createNewFile ();                    
                        System.out.println("The file was created as db.txt");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }

            }while (!outputFile.exists()) ;

            try
            {
                // Define which file to stream in from

                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("db.txt") ;
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (fileIn) ;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (input)) ;
                String line ;

                // Read each line of the file

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    // insert code to break input to pieces
                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line) ;
                    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        Link record = new Link() ;
                        record.setBookName(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                        record.setBookAuthor(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                        record.setIsbn(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                        record.setPublicYear(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                    }
                    System.out.println (line) ;
                }

                input.close() ;
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Error. Could not read the file") ;
            }
            list.printList();


            /**list.insert(123456, "kostis", "kostis", 1900);
            list.insert(123456, "kostis", "kostis", 1900);
            list.insert(123456, "kostis", "kostis", 1900);
            list.insert(123456, "kostis", "kostis", 1900);
            list.insert(123456, "kostis", "kostis", 1900);
            **/



    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding your record to your list?  I'm not finding that part.

Comment: can you post what it prints, the raw text file data that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you put anything into the list thus I assume the `printList()` method will only print a single empty line.

The raw text file data seems to come from this line:

```
System.out.println (line) ;
```

I assume you want your reading code to be something like this (although I doubt the inner while would/should be necessary):

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   // insert code to break input to pieces
   StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line) ;
   while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
   {
     String bookName = tokenizer.nextToken();
     String author = tokenizer.nextToken();
     String isbn = tokenizer.nextToken();
     String year = tokenizer.nextToken();

     list.insert(bookName, author, isbn, year) ;
   }
   System.out.println (line) ;
}
```

Additionally, this seems odd:

```
Link currentLink = new Link() ;
currentLink = first;
```

Why not just the following?

```
Link currentLink = first;
```

There are other style problems as well, but I won't comment on those for now.

Comment: You are right. i did not see that System.out.println(line). i removed it and now it prints nothing

Comment: @SergiosSchizas Yes, that's because you don't add anything to the list. See my update for a possible solution. As I already said your code contains a lot of stylistic/design problems and would require some heavy refactoring, thus don't expect the proposed solution to be perfect.

Comment: Thank You! you have been very helpful!

Comment: any idea on how to count the nodes (entries in the text file) so that once the user runs the program, it will show the number of entries?

Comment: @SergiosSchizas Assuming you have one node per line just read the number of lines or the number of entries in the list. If you want to know the number of lines before reading all the lines you'd need to store that information somewhere or otherwise guess based on the file size.

Comment: you are right again. thanks alot! i went with line count approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your are just printing

```
System.out.println (line) ;
```

You never add the record to the list so the line

```
list.printList();
```

does nothing.
In your while loop you should add your record to the list.

The following:

```
while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
{
      Link record = new Link() ;
      record.setBookName(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
      record.setBookAuthor(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
      record.setIsbn(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
      record.setPublicYear(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
}
```

Should be:

```
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
   {
       list.insert(values go here);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    // insert code to break input to pieces
                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line) ;
                    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        Link record = new Link() ;
                        record.setBookName(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                        record.setBookAuthor(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                        record.setIsbn(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                        record.setPublicYear(tokenizer.nextToken()) ;
                    }
                    System.out.println (line) ;
                }
```

You are creating the `new Link()` for each record, populating it, and **never adding it to the list**. It prints the raw data because you have that `System.out.println(line);` in there.